# Rest_framework_swagger without authorization in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I have the following settings for REST_FRAMEWORK in my django project:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',),
    ...
}
```

I want to see all methods in rest_framework_swagger without authorization. I know that by default swagger doesn't show the methods you don't have access to. How can I override it?

I have already tried to experiment with SWAGGER_SETTINGS in my settings.py file but it seems to me that is hasn't 'no authorization' option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `drf_yasg` library for swagger, which is recommended by DRF, you can use these schema_view settings:

```
# urls.py
from rest_framework import permissions

from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view


schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="My API"
        # other info...
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! We need to add a default_version obligatorily in openapi.Info method.